# how i can define dropdown with multiple selection in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

how i can define dropdown with multiple selection in jquery datatable, i am using the following code pls advise me:

```
aoColumns: [      null,
                    null,
                    null,null,
                    { type: "date-range" },
                    { type: "select",values:['1', '2', '3','4','5']},
                    { type: "date-range" },
                    { type: "text" },
                    null,
                    null,

                ]});
```

Comment: It is not clear for me what exactly you are trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery chosen plugin: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen

and put this code:

```
var selectMulti = "<select class='chosen' multiple='true' style='width:200px;'>"
                    + "<option>1</option>"
                    + "<option>2</option>"
                    + "<option>3</option>"
                    + "<option>4</option>"
                    + "<option>5</option>"
                + "</select>";

//inside the constructor of datatable, put this:
aoColumns: [      null,
                    null,
                    null,null,
                    { "type": "date-range" },
                    { "sTitle" : selectMulti},
                    { "type": "date-range" },
                    { "type": "text" },
                    null,
                    null,

                ]});

//after build the datatable, run this code
$(".chosen").chosen();
```